# How to prevent/override authorization header in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

I have web page under `/` which requires Basic auth. Under `/api/*` REST API is served which does require JWT token passed in Authorization header.

In Chrome it works fine: when I load web page it asks me for Basic credentials and then webpage performs AJAX requests to `/api/*` along with JWT in Authorization header.

In Safari however, all AJAX requests are sent with Authorization header set to Basic credentials, and does not allow to set JWT in Authorization header...

Is there any workaround for this situation?

I am setting JWT for AJAX requests like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {'Authorization': accessToken}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and probably it's a bug in Safari.

The request from Safari:

[image]

The same request in Wireshark:

[image]

Solution: don't use basic auth or change the authorization header name (e.g. use `X-My-Api-Auth`).

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similair situation, it worked fine in Chrome/Firefox but Edge and mobile browsers had issues. The only problem i had was that i could not change the header that is used for JWT authentication (Authorization).

So instead, i used a custom header for the JWT token in my client app:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {'X-JWT': accessToken}
});
```

And in my webserver config (Nginx), i overwrite the `Authorization` header with my custom JWT header `X-JWT`:

```
        underscores_in_headers on;

        location /api/ {
                auth_basic off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002/;
                proxy_set_header Authorization $http_x_jwt;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
```